# Insert flip checkbox button value dynamically in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bdd

I'm making a jQuery application. I have a switch button which is either activated or not. I need to insert the button's value (on or off) in a mysql database, at the exact moment when I switch it. Any suggestions how could do that ?

```
        <form>
            <label for="flip-checkbox-1">State :</label>
            <input name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch">
        </form>
```

Comment: you want to fire event (insert) on button switch?

Comment: @MahaDev fire event could be the solution to insert the value in the database when i switch it?

Comment: I don't know what html you are using, please show me your html

Comment: @MahaDev sorry, i just added in a formula ... below is my html

Comment: Still unclear, but probably you want to update database on checkbox on and off, write?

Comment: yes! sorry don't want to be unclear. Its exactly that, i want to update the database on checkbox on and off write

Comment: use jquery onchange event (input checkbox) and send ajax call with checkbox value to update dataase

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a good website who explains how to manipulate database with ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will be like this, please see further by yourself

```
$("#flip-checkbox-1").change(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    url:"php_file_url.php",
    data: {'checkbox_val' : val },
    success:function(results){
       console.log(results);
     }});

   });
```

Comment: @maevy Please upvote and accept this answer, as it has seemed to help you out.